# Check Version with string c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

EDIT:

Simple example how I want to check:

I have a `string` that contains: "0101".

I want to check if that `string` is at least 0101 or Higher, without converting it to an `int`, because that would change my `string` to: 101.

EDIT:

Answer looks like this:

```
 private void VersionCheck(string version)
        {
            string firmwareVersion = version.Substring(0, 4);
            string biosVersion = version.Substring(4, 4);

            var isEqualOrHigherFirmwareVersion = string.Compare(firmwareVersion, Settings.MinimalFirmwareUnikon, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, CompareOptions.None) >= 0;

        if (!isEqualOrHigherFirmwareVersion)
        {
            _serial.ClosePortConnection();
            DisplayLog("CLOCK: Firmware NOT OK : Unsupported version");
        MessageBox.Show("Unsupported clock Firmware!", "Firmware", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            DisplayLog("CLOCK: Firmware OK : v" + firmwareVersion.ToString());
        }

        var isEqualOrHigherBiosVersion = string.Compare(biosVersion,     `Settings.MinimalBiosUnikon, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, CompareOptions.None) >= 0;`

        if (!isEqualOrHigherBiosVersion)
        {
            _serial.ClosePortConnection();
            DisplayLog("CLOCK: BIOS NOT OK : Unsupported version");
            MessageBox.Show("Unsupported clock BIOS version!", "BIOS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            DisplayLog("CLOCK: BIOS OK : v" + biosVersion.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: The sampleVersion has 5 chars instead of 8.

Comment: No it is just a sample like, how can I check if a number in a string is at least an x number? Without having it converted to an int

Comment: `int parsed; var isParsed=int.TryParse(sampleVersion, out parsed); if(isParsed) return parsed <= x; return false;`

Comment: Your example and question shows that there is an implied decimal point somewhere within `sampleVersion`. So, split the version at that point and you can now convert to int without loss. If there is no implied decimal point, then of course the problem cannot be solved.

Comment: @Mobstaa: It's not just a sample, your sample changes all. You have mentioned that _"The first 4 characters from the Versionstring are the Firmware version and the last 4 characters are the BIOS version"_ The sample contradicts this rule.

Comment: You said that you receive a character string of length 8, but `simpleVersion` is of length 5. That certailnly will not work. If you receive a string of numbers with length 8, all works fine.

Comment: 0101 == 101;
0011 == 11; Just cast a temp variable and test, math still holds true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var input = "0102";
var supportedVersion = "0101";
var isGreaterOrHigher = string.Compare(input, supportedVersion, 
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, CompareOptions.None) >= 0;
```

But what's wrong with `int.Parse/int.TryParse`?